# Angular 6 API JSON ngFor Not Showing

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, angular6

I am working on a project using Angular 6 for the first time, and I am creating an application that gets JSON data from an online URL, listing each entry on a HTML page. Each entry has a variable key value, paired with an array of variables. The problem is that, despite not showing any errors, the *ngFor statement does not show any of the entries, yet the {{ jsonData | json }} shows that the data is returned successfully. Here is my code.

**api-retrieval-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { CoinListing } from './coinListing';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiRetrievalService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  coinList() {
    return this._http.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist').pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
     return throwError(error);
  }
}
```

**coinlist.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiRetrievalService } from '../api-retrieval.service';
import { CoinListing } from '../coinListing';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-coinlist',
  templateUrl: './coinlist.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class CoinlistComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Coin Listing';
  public _jsonData:CoinListing[] = [];
  constructor(private _apiRetrieval: ApiRetrievalService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._apiRetrieval.coinList()
      .subscribe(
        result =>  {
          this._jsonData = result.Data;
          console.log('Success', result.Data);
        },
        error => this.errorMsg = error.statusText
     );
  }
}
```

**coinListing.ts**

```
export interface CoinListing {
  [key:string]: {
    Algorithm: string;
    BuiltOn: string;
    CoinName: string;
    FullName: string;
    FullyPremined: string;
    Id: string;
    ImageUrl: string;
    IsTrading: string;
    Name: string;
    PreMinedValue: string;
    ProofType: string;
    SmartContractAddress: string;
    SortOrder: string;
    Sponsored: string;
    Symbol: string;
    TotalCoinSupply: string;
    TotalCoinsFreeFloat: string;
    Url: string;
  }
};
```

**coinlist.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{ title }}
  </h1>
</div>
<br/>
<p *ngFor="let coin of _jsonData">
 Found {{ coin }}
</p>
```

Anyone know what is stopping the CoinListings from being displayed via *ngFor? Or how I can show each CoinListing's variables in the HTML page, given their structure?

Comment: Have you tried to output using `{{_jsonData | json}}` and look if everything is correct in the structure?

Comment: I already have, and I tried ordering the variables in the CoinListing interface file as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the properties or use the **json pipe** the `{{_jsonData | json}}` is working because you are telling the binding to give it that structure with the **json pipe**

To learn more about JSON pipes:
https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

You can do this:

```
<p *ngFor="let coin of _jsonData">
  Found {{ coin | json }}
<p>
```

or binding each property you want to show

```
 <p *ngFor="let coin of _jsonData">
      Found:
      {{  coin.Algorithm }}
      {{  coin.BuiltOn }}
      .
      .
      .
      {{  coin.Url }}
 <p>
```

**UPDATE: Based on the structure of your object**

```
<div *ngFor="let coin of objectKeys(_jsonData)">
    {{_jsonData[coin] | json}}
</div>
```

**In your ts file:**

```
objectKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it comes up with the following...

Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed at DefaultIterableDiffer.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:5642)

Comment: @ScH88 did you try both solutions?

Comment: your problem is in this line right here `this._jsonData = result.Data;` can you post in your question part of the structure you are getting back from results.Data? result.Data is not an array of objects. Looks like is just an Object @ScH88

Comment: I tried both. I included the ".Data" because is a part of the return value itself and is all I need. The full return value is {Response: "Success", Message: "Coin list succesfully returned!", Data: {…}, BaseImageUrl: "https://www.cryptocompare.com", BaseLinkUrl: "https://www.cryptocompare.com"}

Comment: And as for what ".Data" returns, here's a line. 

0XBTC: {Id: "877383", Url: "/coins/0xbtc/overview", ImageUrl: "/media/32655871/0xbtc.jpg", Name: "0xBTC", Symbol: "0XBTC", …}

Comment: yep... so the issue is that you Object has the `0XBTC:{...}` you can either do 2 things. loop through and array with keys that contain objects or remove the keys basically if you remove the 0XBTC your object will be like this `{...}`

Comment: Just did, and having tried your code, it works now. I am able to get each item and their variables. Much thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried. It said something about votes from those with less than 15 reputation being recorded but not changing the public score.

Comment: @ScH88 that's right. Well when you get enough reputation don't forget about your homies ;) hahah

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, "Each entry has a variable key value, paired with an array of variables" then coins is an object or array. If that is the case then

```
Found {{ coin }}
```

will not return a value. You would need to call a variable from inside coin. For example if 'title' was a key inside of coin then you could do

```
Found {{ coin.title }}
```

Comment: ng-repeat is not used in Angular. That's for AngularJS https://namitamalik.github.io/NgRepeat-vs-ngFor/

Comment: Thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

You need to use property like below

```
<p *ngFor="let coin of _jsonData">
 Found {{ coin.Title }}
</p>
```